# Wordpress categories hooks

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I need when the user edits a category I want to add another text field so the user can set a color for that category, is this posibile?I will upload a picture so you can see what I mean [image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try your question here too --> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't going to get the new field EXACTLY where you want it, but here you go. Place this in your functions.php file to give your categories a color selection of Black or White:

```
<?php
add_action('edit_category_form', 'add_extra_fields');
add_action('edited_category', 'save_extra_fields');
function add_extra_fields($tag)
{
    $colors = array('Black' => '000', 'White' => 'FFF');
    $selected = get_option('category_'.$tag->term_id.'_color');
    echo '<select name="cat_color">';
    foreach($colors as $name => $hex)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$hex.'"'.($hex == $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
function save_extra_fields($term_id)
{
    if($_POST['cat_color'])
    {
        update_option('category_'.$term_id.'_color', $_POST['cat_color']);
    }
}
?>
```

You can add more labels and values to the color array as you see fit.

Comment: Lots and lots of reading and experimenting: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: I think I love you, maiorano84.